# how to get the same certificate if I want to load certificate from specific provider, from keystore?

Tags: java, security, certificate, digital-signature, pki

I have a .p12 file, and I load it with specified provider to keystore, and now I get an encoded certificate and converted to base64 encoding, after this I pass it through the network to server side, on server side I get it in base64 format, decode to normal, and parse to Certificate type, but, when I use it to check the signiture it gives exception

```
javaenter code here.lang.ClassCastException: "myprovider".JCEECPublicKey cannot be cast to java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey
```

code, which raise this exception:

```
Certificate cert = null;
            try {
                cert = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(cert_array));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

if (cert != null) {

                boolean ret = false;
                try {
                    //load with specific crypto provider
                    Signature sgn = Signature.getInstance("ECGOST34310", "GAMMA");
                    sgn.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());
                    sgn.update(textBlob);
                    ret = sgn.verify(sign);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                //signature check
                if (ret) {
                    System.out.println("verify sign OK");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("verify sign FALSE");
                }
            }
```

clients side code, which take generate certificate:

```
KeyStore store = loadKeyStorep12(fileName, pass);
            Enumeration en = store.aliases();
            while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
                StoreObjectParam profParam = (StoreObjectParam) en.nextElement();
                System.out.println(profParam);
                aliasKey = profParam.getSn();
            }
            PrivateKey prvKey = (PrivateKey) store.getKey(aliasKey, pass.toCharArray());
            if (prvKey != null) {
                byte[] textBlob = loadDocument(filePath);
                sign = SetSign(textBlob, prvKey);
                Certificate cert = store.getCertificate(aliasKey);
                certificate = cert.getEncoded();
```

after this certificate is send to server side

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the exception?  In your CertificateFactory call?  Or when trying to validate the signature?

Comment: Thanks a lot for attention, but the problem is solved, I have to defime explicitly my provider, e.i. CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "GAMMA")...